# Unknown Get calls are received and logged in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an instance of APIM which hosts multiple APIs. This include multiple post operations.
I have observed many **Get** calls being logged for the endpoint which are actually **Post**. I verified from client who uses it and they are not making any get calls for the same. When I searched IPs logged in app insights it belongs to Microsoft.

[image]

Where the actual API is post operation as shown below

[image]

May I know why these get calls are made? Is there any possibility these are from APIM?

Answer (score 1):

I raised Microsoft ticket to understand why we are getting unknown Get calls. They analyzed IP address where its coming from then they got to know its coming from Microsoft Teams. If somebody post URL in Teams, then Teams trying to render the url in order to get some information to show in the chat. In this attempt it makes a Get calls